# Pytorch operation for moving vectors between torch tensors

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor

Assuming we have the torch tensors:

```
A: with shape BxHxW and values in {0,1}, where 0 and 1 are classes
B: with shape Bx2xD and real values, where D is the dimensionality of our vector

We want to create a new tensor of shape BxDxHxW that holds in each index specified in the spatial dimension (HxW), the vector that corresponds to its class (specified by A).
```

Is there a function in pytorch that implements that? I tried torch scatter but think this is not the case.

Comment: You seem to use `B` twice in your answer, once as a tensor name, once as a dimension size. So let me paraphrase your question: Given a classes tensor `c` of shape `[B,H,W]` and a vector tensor `v` of shape `[B,2,D]`, where the second dimensions corresponds to the possible classes `0` or `1`, you are looking for an efficient way to compute the tensor `result` of shape `[B,D,H,W]`, such that
`result[b,d,h,w] = v[b, c[h,w], d]`. Correct? If yes, this is in fact somewhat different from `torch.gather` and quite interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for the reverse operation, namely gathering values from one tensor using indices contained in another.
Here is a canonical answer to deal with this kind of indexing scenario and apply [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) without much trouble.

Let's set up a minimal example with dummy data:

```
>>> b = 2; d = 3; h = 2; w = 1
>>> A = torch.randint(0, 2, (b,h,w)) # bhw
>>> B = torch.rand(b,2,d) # b2d
```

1. Define the indexing rule you want to perform according to your problem, here:

   ```
   # out[b, d, h, w] = B[b, A[b, h, w]]
   ```
2. We are looking for some kind of indexing of `B`'s 2nd dimension using the values in `A`. When applying `torch.gather` all three tensors (input, indexer, and output) must have the ***same number of dimensions*** and the ***same dimension sizes*** except for the dimension that is being indexed, *i.e.* here `dim=1`. Observing our case, we have to stick to this pattern:

   ```
   # out[b, 1, d, h, w] = B[b, A[b, 1, d, h, w], d, h, w]
   ```
3. So in order to account for this change, we need to unsqueeze/expand additional dimensions on both our input and index tensors. Therefore, to stick with the above shapes, we can do:

   First, we unsqueeze two dimension on `A`:

   ```
   >>> A_ = A[:,None,None].expand(-1,1,d,-1,-1)
   ```

   Second, we unsqueeze two dimensions on `B`:

   ```
   >>> B_ = B[..., None, None].expand(-1,-1,-1,h,w)
   ```

   Note, that expanding a dimension does not perform a copy. It is merely a view on the tensor's underlying data. At this step `A_` ends up having a shape of `(b, 1, d, h, w)`, while `B_` has a shape of `(b, 2, d, h, w)`.
4. Now, we can simply apply `torch.gather` on `dim=1` using `A_` and `B_`:

   ```
   >>> out = B_.gather(dim=1, index=A_)
   ```

   We had to use a singleton dimension for `dim=1`, so we can squeeze it on the resulting tensor. This is your desired result shaped `(b, d, h, w)`:

   ```
   >>> out[:,0]
   ```